# Calculate sample size based on Conversion Rate, Minimum Detectable Effect, Statistical power and Significance level

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, ab-test

How to calculate sample size based on  Conversion Rate, Minimum Detectable Effect, Statistical power and Significance level. I find two very good online tools that calculate it http://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html  and http://www.adobe-target.com/testcalculator.html (they results are very close). I can't find formla how to calculate this manually.. I tried to calculate myself but got different(much larger) results.

Answer (score 6):

I feel your pain. I blew so many hours yesterday looking at sites like:

- http://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html#!3;80;5;20;1
- https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~rollin/stats/ssize/b2.html
- https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/sample-size-calculator-two-proportions/

And none of them provided a formula, which was disappointing, but the really aggravating part was that *their results did not match each other's!*

*Finally*, I found a [formula](https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/sample-size-calculator-two-proportions/):

$n = (Z_{α/2}+Z_β)^2 * (p_1(1-p_1)+p_2(1-p_2)) / (p_1-p_2)^2$

Then it took me several more hours to convert it to an Excel formula that I could actually use, such as:

`=(-NORMSINV(0.05/2)+normsinv(0.8))^2*(0.03*(1-0.03)+0.036*(1-0.036))/(0.03-0.036)^2` = 13,911 (Required Observations Per Variation)

([This calculator's](https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/sample-size-calculator-two-proportions/) result matches that of my Excel formula, which is comforting.)

If this answer looks helpful, please upvote.

And see [What to do after calculating the required sample size for a Marketing A-B test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/355195/29511) for more context.

Answer (score 0):

This calculator has the formulas:
http://powerandsamplesize.com/Calculators/Compare-2-Proportions/2-Sample-Equality
for pB you need to enter pA+MDE, I believe.